# JayData and Angular - Save Form Data

Tags: angularjs, jaydata

I am new to Angular and Jaydata. I need to grab data from a drop down and save it to Jay data. I am not sure at all what I am missing. This is what I have.

In the index.html page I have a drop down and a button to save the data when clicked.
Can someone please help me understand what I need to do here?  Thanks

```
<select id="year" name="Year" class="input-large" ng-model="year"  >
    <option value="0" selected=""disabled="">&lt;Year&gt;</option>
    <select id="year" name="Year" class="input-large" ng-model="year"  >
        <option value="0" selected="" disabled="">&lt;Year&gt;</option>
        <option value="2001">2001</option>
        <option value="2002">2002</option>
        <option value="2003">2003</option>
        <option value="2004">2004</option>
        <option value="2005">2005</option>
        <option value="2006">2006</option>
        <option value="2007">2007</option>
        <option value="2008">2008</option>
        <option value="2009">2009</option>
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
    </select>
    <footer>
        <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="save()" >
            Save
            </button>
        </footer>
```

In the indexcontroller I have:

```
var controllerId = 'indexcontroller';
angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['common', 'datacontext', indexcontroller]);

function indexcontroller($scope,common, datacontext) {


    $scope.save = function Save() {

        myDB.onReady(function () {
            //trying to add year from the drop down here
            myDB.ScoreData.add({ Year: $scope.year });
            myDB.saveChanges();
        });

    }
}
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to pass in $scope.
:)
var controllerId = 'indexcontroller';
angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, [**'$scope'**,'common', 'datacontext', indexcontroller]);